# What is the difference between the different GCC on Cygwin, and which one to install?

Tags: cygwin, gcc, mingw

I need to install GCC for Cywin, but I see that there are five different "gcc-g++" packages:

- cygwin32-gcc-g++
- gcc-g++
- mingw-gcc-g++
- mingw64-i686-gcc-g++
- mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++

What is the difference between them and which one is generally recommended? (for a 64-bit machine). Ideally, I'd like to install just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names are quite clear to me:

- cygwin32-gcc-g++ is a compiler for 32 bit cygwin
- gcc-g++ is the basic 64 bit compiler (you probably must install this one).
- mingw-gcc-g++ is a 32 bit compiler for native 32 bit Windows
- mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++ is a 64 bit compiler for native 64 bit Windows
- mingw64-i686-gcc-g++ is a 64 bit compiler for native 32 bit Windows

So it all depends if you run in a 64 bit Windows and what target you want (cygwin or native Windows).

Comment: `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` is listed twice.

Comment: The "magic" of cut & paste!